# Constants in MongoDB using Moingoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, constants, mongoid3, database

Are there any good common practices for storing project-wide constants in Mongodb via Mongoid?  Is it even worth keeping them in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constants are, well, constants. Pi is a constant. You don't need a database for it, you know its value. But probably you meant something more like "A value that's pretty static and is unlikely to change often". If this is the case, then it indeed makes some sense to store those values in a DB. There are probably gems for this kind of stuff, but in vanilla Mongoid I'd do something like this:

```
class Setting
  field :_id, type: String
  field :value

  def self.read_value name
    # return value or nil
    Setting.where(_id: name).first.try(:value)
  end

  def self.write_value name, value
    where(_id: name).upsert(value: value)
  end
end

# usage
num_workers = Setting.read_value 'number_of_workers'
Setting.write_value "upload_dir", '/var/www/uploads'
```